# Shell script run with mac address validate

Tags: linux, shell, mac-address

Can we run shell script with check system mac address validation then process.

```
#!/bin/bash

### here i need to check system mac address 
### if mac is not match then script will not run
killall gnome-terminal
echo "End Of Day Session Complete"
```

plz suggest

Comment: Why killall and not just exit?

Answer (score 1):

Why not. First get the `mac address` of your system and store it in a variable in your shell script or in a config file. Every time when you run the script first get the `mac address` of the system and compare with the mac id already stored in your script's variable if same continue and if not just exit. Use `ifconfig -a` command to get the mac address of your system and store it in a config file or in your script.

Answer (score 0):

A hardware adress can be obtained like this:

```
LC_ALL=C ifconfig | egrep "HWaddr" | awk '{print $5}'
```

but note:

- there might be more than one interface with a mac
- on many systems, the mac can be spoofed

To suspend work, just exit. Don't killall, and if you do, don't expect later echo messages to be seen by someone.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to run your code on multiple systems, you could use an associative array to store the MAC addresses of the systems where the script is to be run

```
declare -A valid_mac
valid_mac["00:00:00:00:00:00"]=1
valid_mac["00:00:00:00:00:01"]=1
valid_mac["00:00:00:00:00:02"]=1
```

Your script function is to terminate all gnome-terminal sessions on each machine where it is run if the mac address is valid.

Let's define a function

```
function kill_all_terms(){
    killall gnome-terminal
    echo "End Of Day Session Complete"
}
```

Now on each machine you want to get a list of MAC addresses of this machine. There are many ways to do it. The function below lists MAC addresses of all IPv4 interfaces using shell string parsing capabilities

```
function macs(){
   local macs line l1
   while read line ; do 
     l1="${line#*link/ether }"  ; 
     macs="${l1% brd*} ${macs}" ; 
   done < <( ip -4 -o link ) ;
   echo "${macs}"
}
```

Now we can define the main loop

```
function main() {
   for mac in $(macs) ; do
      if [ -n "${valid_mac[$mac]}" ] ; then 
         kill_all_terms
         break
      fi
   done
}
```

Finally just run `main()` as

```
 main "$@"
```